# Is the shorthand electron configuration of Br- just [Kr]?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electronic-configuration

Is the shorthand electron configuration of $\ce{Br-}$ just $\ce{[Kr]}$?

Also what about $\ce{Ca^2+}$—is it just $\ce{[Ar]}$? And, is $\ce{Na+}$ just $\ce{[Ne]}$?

Comment: I meant is Na+ just [Ne]

Comment: Welcome to Chem.SE! I edited the post to reflect your change; you could have edited it yourself, though -- see the 'edit' link in gray at the bottom-left of your post.  Please take a look at the [tour] and [help] for more information about our site and community.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could render bromide ion that way.  But the outermost electrons in the "krypton core" are potentially reactive, valence electrons; therefore $\text{[Kr]}$ is not an accurate description of how the electrons really act.  Only the *argon* core acts like a noble gas, so you are better off rendering the bromide ion as $\text{[Ar]3d}^{10}\text{4s}^2\text{4p}^6$.

Cations stripped to the noble gas core, however, really are stripped to unreactive electrons, so calcium ion can accurately be rendered as $\text{[Ar]}$.